# EntityManager from container in SpringBeanAutowiringInterceptor-created context

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, ejb, entitymanager

I have an EJB that's annotated as follows:

```
@Stateless
@Interceptors(SpringBeanAutowiringInterceptor.class)
```

The `SpringBeanAutowiringInterceptor` creates a `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext` which in turn creates some `@Component`s. One of these `@Component`s is a DAO and thus likes to get an `EntityManager` injected. Preferably this should be the EJB's container-managed `EntityManager` (as per my current insights).

If I add to the EJB the following, that works just fine:

```
@PersistenceContext
EntityManager entityManager;
```

If I however do the latter on my DAO (which is in Spring which is its own context) that does not work. Regardless of whether I call out the unit name specifically or not (`unitName="test"`, "`No bean named 'test' is defined`" versus "`No unique bean of type [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory]`").

I've tried `jee:jndi-lookup` in Spring, but I'm at a loss of how to make the entity manager available in JNDI for that to work. Should that be somehow done in my `persistence.xml` or even at another level?

I'm running all this in JBOSS as an Arquillian test, but my target environment is WAS. I should thus also steer away from container-specific solutions. This is not a WAR project, rather shrinkwrapping the EJB JAR in an EAR.

I think I'm looking for the general concept or the best practice here, to move me forward. (Hence I limited the amount of code included in the question, though I'm happy to share some specifics if that'd help.) Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4717196/1850609

Answer (score 0):

add the following to your Spring Config

```
<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />
```