# EntityManager is null. Cannot inject

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, entitymanager

I'm trying to connect my project with db. I have one project that is already connected and operates on this db. And i need second one and communication between them using jms. I configure secon to connect to the same db and it isn`t working. Well connection is ok. When i create Entity class then in db i see new table. So great. But i wrote controller that should inject entity manager and it's always null. i don't have idea why. Here is my config.

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "**.*****.**********" })
public class CalculationWorkerRootConfig {

    @Bean
    public static PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer propertyPlaceholderConfigurer() {
        PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer ppc = new PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer();
        ppc.setLocation(new ClassPathResource("/persistence.properties"));
        return ppc;
    }

}
```

Here is manager configurer:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories
public class CalculationWorkerPersistenceConfig implements TransactionManagementConfigurer {

    @Value("${dataSource.driverClassName}")
    private String driver;
    @Value("${dataSource.url}")
    private String url;
    @Value("${dataSource.username}")
    private String username;
    @Value("${dataSource.password}")
    private String password;
    @Value("${hibernate.dialect}")
    private String dialect;
    @Value("${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}")
    private String hbm2ddlAuto;

@Bean
public DataSource configureDataSource() {
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName(driver);
    dataSource.setUrl(url);
    dataSource.setUsername(username);
    dataSource.setPassword(password);
    return dataSource;
}

@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean configureEntityManagerFactory() {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(configureDataSource());
    entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan("**.*********.************");
    entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter());

    Properties jpaProperties = new Properties();
    jpaProperties.put(org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.DIALECT, dialect);
    jpaProperties.put(org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.HBM2DDL_AUTO, hbm2ddlAuto);
    entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaProperties(jpaProperties);

    return entityManagerFactoryBean;
}

@Bean   
public PlatformTransactionManager annotationDrivenTransactionManager() {
    return new JpaTransactionManager();
}

}
```

And here is repository:

```
@Repository
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public class CalculationWorkerRepository {

@PersistenceContext
EntityManager entityManager; 


public Campaign findByID(Long id) {
    return entityManager.find(Campaign.class, id);
}

@Transactional
public void setCalculating(Boolean calculating, Long campaignID) {
    Campaign campaign = findByID(campaignID);
    campaign.setCalculating(calculating);
}

}
```

Comment: Can you show the Controller?

Answer (score 9):

The class `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean` is a factory. You'll notice from the [javadoc](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/jpa/LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.html) that it extends [`AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/jpa/AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.html) which provides the methods `afterPropertiesSet()` and `getObject()`. You need to call these to instantiate an `EntityManagerFactory`.

```
@Bean
public EntityManagerFactory configureEntityManagerFactory() {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(configureDataSource());
    entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan("**.*********.************");
    entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter());

    Properties jpaProperties = new Properties();
    jpaProperties.put(org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.DIALECT, dialect);
    jpaProperties.put(org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.HBM2DDL_AUTO, hbm2ddlAuto);
    entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaProperties(jpaProperties);

    entityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();
    return (EntityManagerFactory) entityManagerFactoryBean.getObject();
}
```

The above will create an `EntityManagerFactory`. You then need an [`EntityManager`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManagerFactory.html) bean.

```
@Bean
public EntityManager entityManager() {
    return configureEntityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From what I see you are only instantiating an `EntityManagerFactory` and not an `EntityManager`, so either you have to inject the `EntityManagerFactory` or instatntiate an `EntityManager` at start up that can be injected.

Also note the problems described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4708035/persistencecontext-entitymanager-injection-nullpointerexception) post regarding injection of an EM in relation to transactions and different environments.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `JpaTransactionManager` is missing a reference to an `EntityManagerFactory`. Use either constructor injection or setter injection to solve it:

```
@Bean   
public PlatformTransactionManager annotationDrivenTransactionManager() {
    return new JpaTransactionManager(configureEntityManagerFactory());
}
```

or

```
@Bean   
public PlatformTransactionManager annotationDrivenTransactionManager() {
    JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
    transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(configureEntityManagerFactory());
    return transactionManager;
}
```

Reference, the `JpaTransactionManager` in the XML application context in the [JPA Transaction paragraph](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/orm.html#orm-jpa-tx) in the Spring reference documentation has a corresponding configuration.