# Injecting EntityManager using Spring ( Null Pointer Exception )

Tags: spring, entitymanager

Here's the code insidy my ApplicationContext.xml

```
    <context:spring-configured />
<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.apsas.jpa" />
<tx:annotation-driven />

<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="testjpa" />
</bean>

<bean id="entityManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.SharedEntityManagerBean">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />
```

and here's my Dao Implementation

```
public class TeacherDaoImpl implements TeacherDao {

@Autowired
private EntityManager entityManager;

@Transactional
public Teacher addTeacher(Teacher teacher) {
    entityManager.persist(teacher);
    return teacher;

}
```

}

Here's my Main Class

```
public class TestApp {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    ApplicationContext applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
            "config/ApplicationContext.xml");       

    TeacherDao teacherDao = new TeacherDaoImpl();       
    Teacher teacher1 =  teacherDao.addTeacher(new Teacher("First Teacher"));

}
```

}

Please help, i am getting a null pointer exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.apsas.jpa.dao.impl.TeacherDaoImpl.addTeacher(TeacherDaoImpl.java:22)
at com.apsas.jpa.main.TestApp.main(TestApp.java:26)
```

ive been solving this problem in 2 days but still i cant find any resources that may solve this problem. i appreciate if you give me your opinion,answers or any idea that might help me solving this,

ps: i am new on learning spring

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you are instantiating `TeacherDaoImpl` yourself (with the `new` keyword) within main, Spring is not injecting the `EntityManager` and hence the NPE.

Annotate the field `TeacherDaoImpl.entityManager` with `@PersistenceContext` and annotate the `TeacherDaoImpl` class with `@Component` to have Spring instantiate it for you. Then in your main, get a hold of that bean:

```
TeacherDao dao = applicationContext.getBean(TeacherDao.class);
// ...
```

Also these two directives seem to be unnecessary:

```
<context:annotation-config />
<context:spring-configured />
```

The former is implied when you are using `<context:component-scan />`. The latter is only useful if you are using `@Configurable` in your code.

Comment: Hi Thanks, seems im near on solving this problem, new error came up
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'transactionManager' is defined

Comment: Do you know what are the exact  class that will be added on bean as a transactionmanager?

Comment: Its now working, i just added <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
  <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
 </bean>

Comment: Next Question, How will i automatically use the TeacherDao using anotationt, without using of = applicationContext.getBean(TeacherDao.class);

Comment: If you wish to use the new keyword and still have dependencies injected, google for @Configurable and AspectJ with Spring. Raise a new stackoverflow question if necessary. But do spend some time/thought on it first.

Comment: Anywat, just wanted to say thank you very much. :) im glad its now working, maybe i cant do an autoinject because im using it on J2SE, maybe @Autowired will work on JEE

Answer (score 3):

You will want to use `@PersistenceContext` for injecting the `EntityManager`.

See

[PersistenceContext EntityManager injection NullPointerException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4708035/persistencecontext-entitymanager-injection-nullpointerexception)

which is pretty much the same question.

Comment: Hi, i changed the Autowired annotation above EntityManager field inside TeacherDaoImpl but still no luck,,

please help :)