# EntityManager not injected from factory

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa, spring-security

I'm using JPA/Hibernate to build a web app. I'm using a `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean` with `<property name="packagesToScan" value="<pkg>" />` to build my entities from a java package, and a `jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource` configured for PostgreSQL, so I don't have a defined persistence context.

Can I build an `EntityManager` with these constraints, using either Spring annotations or xml?

EDIT:
I'm using a code of the following form to get a user data for login. In the `Spring Security` context the  `EntityManager` is always null.

```
@Repository
public class UserDao implements UserDetailsService {
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;  // With getter and setter

    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String userName) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
       // Used by spring-security, here entityManager is null
    }

}
```

EDIT2: Added context configuration

```
<context:spring-configured />
<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="<BasePackage>" />
```

EDIT3: Added entity manager factory config:

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="default_unit" />
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="persistenceProviderClass" value="org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence"></property>
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="showSql" value="true" />
            <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect" />
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="<package>" />
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <value>
            hibernate.show_sql=true
            hibernate.format_sql=true
            hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create-drop
            hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files=/loaded-on-startup/import.sql
             <!-- ALSO CHECK IMPORT.SQL -->
        </value>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    /// CONNECTION CONFIG ///
</bean>
```

I also have added `default-autowire="byType"` to my `beans` tag and `autowire="byType"` to the security authentication bean definition.

Comment: HOw do you call the `loadUserByUsername` method?

Comment: I don't do it, Spring Security does it for me, being an authentication provider (that's why I implement UserDetailsService).

Comment: If it isn't injected it isn't in a context that has the entitymanagerfactory and doesn't have a `context:annotation-config` or `context:component-scan`. If it would there would have been an exception during startup telling you dependencies couldn't be found.

Comment: Could it be because I'm using `<mvc:annotation-driven />`? All the tags I put above are in the same file, an `mvc-config.xml`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Take a look [here](http://hantsy.blogspot.in/2013/07/use-native-jpa-api.html) . You need to provide a datasource and use `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean` bean

**Edit**

It may be because of no transaction available.Read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4708035/persistencecontext-entitymanager-injection-nullpointerexception)

Comment: I can't manage to do it still, added a few details above. If you need more just point it to me.

Comment: Could it be possible to share application context.xml?

Comment: I've added my context config.

Comment: And the `EntityManager` configuration please.

Comment: Added `EntityManagerFactory` bean config.

Comment: On application startup there are no errors? The `entityManagerFactory` bean is usccesfully created?

Comment: Yes, it's successfuly created. It connects and creates the table structure and launches the import.sql script correctly.

Comment: Not sure what the problem is here. Though I would try without the`<property name="persistenceUnitName" value="default_unit" />` and ensure persistence.xml is not present in the project.