# JPA entity persist not saving to DB

Tags: java, jpa

**EDIT** So, I switched from Glassfish to Wildfly and was using EclipseLink 2.5.  This code stopped working when I switched, with the below problems.  The entity manager was created with resource local transactions for some reason.

I tried lots of things, but when I switched to Hibernate EM everything worked just fine.
**END EDIT**

I'm using Wildfly 10 and Eclipselink JPA to have a simple Stateless EJB save a record to a database.  The methods are here:

This bean is marked @Stateless

```
@POST
@Override
@Consumes({"application/xml", "application/json"})
public void create(Actor entity) {
    L.info("Creating {}", entity);
    super.create(entity);
    L.info("Created");
}
```

Here is the abstract parent's method:

```
public void create(T entity) {
    //getEntityManager().getTransaction().begin();
    getEntityManager().persist(entity);
    //getEntityManager().flush();
    //getEntityManager().getTransaction().commit();
}
```

If I uncomment the transactional code, it works.

If I add the transaction annotation, it does not work.

Like this, it does not work.

Why?  I though EJBs got container managed transactions and that this should be auto-committed.  Here is my persistence unit definition:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="net.mikeski_auth_war_0.1.0-SNAPSHOTPU" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/PostgresqlDS</jta-data-source>
    <class>entities.Actor</class>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
      <property name="eclipselink.weaving" value="false"/>
      <property name="eclipselink.weaving.fetchgroups" value="false"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="create"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

I know my entity is good because if I add some to the DB the find methods work, and if I get the transactions right the inserts work.  What am I missing?

Comment: try marking it as @Transactional

Comment: Can you post the application context file for transactional annotation

Comment: does not work.  I tried it on the abstract class' method and on the implementation method and both, as well as `@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.CONTAINER)` on the class

Comment: @Sanj - not spring, just jpa

Comment: See if getEntityManager().joinTransaction() helps. Also can you post getEntityManager() source

Comment: Well, that throws an exception and says it's resource local.  How is that if I have declared it like this it's resource local?

Comment: `    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "net.mikeski_auth_war_0.1.0-SNAPSHOTPU")
    private EntityManager em;
` That's my method

Comment: I think your transaction demarcation is a bit buggered. You need to add you AT Transactional to your  AT Stateless and DI your EJB into your servlet (the one with AT POST method.)

Comment: I do not have a servlet, and the transactional annotations are not working becuause I am getting a resource local transactional entity manager

Comment: how do you inject the entity manager?

Answer (score 1):

I would expect that you pass the object to a `Stateless` EJB, even if that EJB does nothing more than call em.persist for you. Here you are mixing functionalities, you are making the REST do the EJB's work and there may be things that you (and I) don't fully understand yet. Further, the `service layer` stateless ejb would presumably have other functions in it, so it's certainly not a waste.

```
@Inject ActorService actorService;

@POST
@Consumes({"application/xml", "application/json"})
public void create(Actor entity) {
    L.info("Creating {}", entity);
    actorService.create(entity);
    L.info("Created");
}
```

and, presumably:

```
@Stateless
public class ActorService {
    @Inject private EntityManager em;

    public create(Actor actor) {
        em.persist(actor);
    }
    .. the rest of the actor service layer
}
```

I think it's more important to understand the expected way to do things than to understand why the unusual isn't working.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm using this setup because that's a Netbeans pattern for generating REST services from entities.  They use the @PersistenceContext annotation to create the EM.  How would I construct the EntityManager in this case to make it available?

Comment: Hi Mikeb, I would say go ahead and use @PersistenceContext in your stateless ejb. Also, yes, I usually use a Resources utility class that produces the PersistenceContext for injection, as is done in all the [Wildfly samples](https://github.com/wildfly/quickstart/blob/10.x/kitchensink/src/main/java/org/jboss/as/quickstarts/kitchensink/util/Resources.java). Also, I think hibernate is much more mature than EclipseLink.

Answer (score 0):

I think injecting the `entityManager` inside the bean class marked with `@Stateless` should work.

If you are getting `entitymanager` in some other class (parent class) try getting it from entityManagerFactory instead of directly injecting it. Are you already doing that in the super class or do you have a getter for injected em.

There could be java ee version issue [as discussed in an answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4717196/668951)
I think that answer should be helpful.

As such, I agree with Nicholas's inputs about separating responsibilities.

Comment: OK, so how do I create the entity manager if not from the @PersistenceContext annotation?

Comment: @mikeb The link in my answer has the relevant code. Or you can use the approach Nicolas mentions with his sample code using Inject annotation

Comment: I tried that, too, and it did not work.  I switched to Hibernate JPA and everything worked just fine.  I guess it's EclipseLink and Wildfly.