# @Autowired returns null

Tags: java, spring-boot

here is my Repository

```
@Service
public class FuneralPricingRepository {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;  //this is null

    public List<FuneralPricing> findAll() {
        return this.em.createNativeQuery("SELECT * FROM FUNERALPRICING").getResultList();
    }
}
```

AS400calls is autowired but funeralPricingRepository is not.

```
public class TestFuneralPremiumProvider implements TestHandler {

    @Autowired
    private As400Calls as400Calls; //this is not null

    @Autowired
    private FuneralPricingRepository funeralPricingRepository; //this is null
```

Please help...

Comment: Check is package of `FuneralPricingRepository` is in `componentscan` path?

Comment: `@Autowired` cannot be `null`. If a dependency cannot be resolved your application will blow up. If that isn't the case you are not using auto wiring or are constructing an instance of `TestFuneralPremiumProvider` yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You're not allowed to inject `EntityManager` this way. Inject `EntityManagerFactory` instead. Then both injections should work.

> An entity manager can only be injected in classes running inside a transaction. In other words, it can only be injected in a EJB. Other classe must use an EntityManagerFactory to create and destroy an EntityManager.

-[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4717196/4723795)

Is your `Repository` in a package in componentscan path? If not yet, add

```
@ComponentScan("com.my.package.where.repository.is")
```

Another thing is your repository. What is the reason not to use `Spring Data JPA`? Simply extend `CRUDRepository` and you'll receive `findAll` and some more methods for free.

Answer (score 0):

I think problem in this

```
TestFuneralPremiumProvider
```

without annotation @Component or declaration bean in config

Comment: Why is `As400Calls` not null then?