# How to deploy EJB 3.1 session bean in a war on Websphere 8.5

Tags: ejb, jersey, websphere, jax-rs, websphere-8

Now I use Jersey to create restful web service on Websphere 8.5.
 I also want the restful web service has the EJB 3.1's capacity.
My restful web service code as follow:

```
@Stateless
@Path("/tagServiceRS/{tagid}")
@Interceptors(TestTagServiceInterceptor.class)
public class TagServiceRS implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5L;
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TagServiceRS.class);


    @EJB
    private TagTestService tagTestService;

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "tag-ejb")
    private EntityManager entityManager;


    @GET
    @Produces("text/plain")
    public String findTagById(@PathParam("tagid") String tagid) {
       return "TAG";
    }


    /**
     * @return the tagTestService
     */
    public TagTestService getTagTestService() {
        return tagTestService;
    }

    /**
     * @param tagTestService the tagTestService to set
     */
    public void setTagTestService(TagTestService tagTestService) {
        this.tagTestService = tagTestService;
    }
```

When I deploy the war on the Websphere 8.5. The TagServiceRS  was successful deployed as a restful  web service.And I test it. It's OK.
But the TagServiceRS was **failed** deploy as a **EJB session bean**. 
The TagServiceRS's **entityManager** and **tagTestService** fields are all **null**.
I see the log, there is no error or warning log.
Below is my TagTestServiceBean code.

```
@Stateless
public class TagTestServiceBean implements TagTestService, Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5L;
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TagTestServiceBean.class);


    @Override
    public Tag testFindTagById(Long id) {
        log.info("testFindTagById ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ invoked for id: {}", id);
        return new Tag();
    }

}

    @Remote
public interface TagTestService extends Serializable {

    /**
     * @param id
     *            the ID from database
     * @return a tag, may null
     */
    Tag testFindTagById(Long id);

}
```

If Any Answers.Thanks a lot.

Comment: Maybe you can try the other approaches mentioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3027834/inject-a-ejb-into-jax-rs-restfull-service

Answer (score 0):

Change the annotation from `@EJB` to `@Resource`

```
@Resource
private TagTestService tagTestService;
```

The class itself need not to be annotated with `@Stateless` annotation.

*Additionally, JAX-RS root resource and provider classes must have a JCDI specified scope. Scopes control the lifecycle of a JCDI managed bean. Root resource classes can have any valid scope such as @javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped, which makes the JAX-RS root resource class behave the same as in a non-JCDI enabled application. The javax.ws.rs.core.Application subclasses and JAX-RS providers must have the @javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped annotation.*

More info [here](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/info/aes/ae/twbs_jaxrs_jcdi.html).