# EJB module and RESTFULL api

Tags: java, rest, jakarta-ee, glassfish, ejb

> I have EJB module that I want to make RESTFULL api.

I do not have any war files. Only EJB.jar file which has been deployed on glassfish server.

Following is my SessionBean class.

```
@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class TestSessionBean {

@GET
@Path("/test")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public JSONObject getObjects(@QueryParam("city") String city) {
    try {

        JSONObject jSONObject = new JSONObject();

        jSONObject.put(city, "test");

        return jSONObject;
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
}
```

My ejb module name as `TestEJB`. I am using `JEE6`. I tried to get resource from googling. but did not get any idea. 
I went [Inject a EJB into JAX-RS (RESTfull service)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3027834/inject-a-ejb-into-jax-rs-restfull-service) and so on. But could not get any usefull resources.

**Note: I heard from one of my friend that it is possible in EJB3 so I tried to do.**

I do not know is it possible or not please kindly guide me.

Answer (score 0):

Well, specification says only that "A JAX-RS application is packaged as a Web application in a .war ﬁle. ", and nothing (or at least I cannot find) about using it in standalone ejb module.

Comment: Actually I heard in ejb3 it is possible so I tried to do and posted question here.

Comment: Although it is possible to implement stateless of singleton EJBs as JAX-RS classes, but as @Guest noted you'll have to [package bean in war](http://java.boot.by/ocewsd6-guide/ch04.html).