# Injection of EJB in Web Application bean

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, dependency-injection, ejb, jndi

I have a Maven project in Eclipse that is deployed as an EAR containing a JAR module (Java 1.7, EJB 3.1 and JPA 2.0 project) and a WAR module (Servlet 3.0, Java 1.7, JAX-RS 1.1). I am deploying it to a Weblogic 12.1.1.0. The structure is as follows:

```
backoffice-ear
    backoffice-ejb-core-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
    backoffice-ws-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war
```

The WS project has classes that implement REST web services that call the Services and Data Access Objects defined as Stateless EJB in the EJB project. Here's an example:

WAR:

```java
@Path("/Events")
@Stateless
public class EventsWS {

    @EJB
    private EventsService eventsService;

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Path("/searchEvents")
    public Response searchEvents() {
       eventsService.searchEvents(null, "S", "TEST", new BigDecimal(1), new BigDecimal(20));
       ...
    }
}
```

JAR:

```java
@Stateless
public class EventsService {

    @EJB
    private EventsDao dao;

    public DtoSearchEvents searchEvents(...) throws ServiceException {
        ...
    }
}
```

The injections work fine inside the JAR module. But between the WAR and JAR they don't.
What happens here is that the injected EJB service in `EventsWS` is always null. But if I load it through JNDI, I am able to use it correctly:

```java
Context context = new InitialContext();
eventsService = (EventsService)context.lookup("java:global/backoffice-ear/backoffice-ejb-core-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/EventsService");
```

But I want to be able to inject the EJB without loading it through JNDI. I already tried using `@EJB's mappedName` attribute with the JDNI path mentioned above but without success. I suppose I am using the correct JNDI path. What am I missing? Let me know if you need more info.

My web.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
  <display-name>backoffice-ws</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

  <servlet>     
    <servlet-name>backoffice-ws-servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>xxx.yyy.zzz.backoffice.ws</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>

    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>backoffice-ws-servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: question is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3027834/inject-a-ejb-into-jax-rs-restfull-service

Answer (score 0):

Your `EventWS` is annotated with `@Stateless`, although it is in the WAR module.  What happens is that your `@Stateless` annotation is ignored (since it's in the WAR), and your `EventWS` bean is not managed, thus no values are injected.

You need to make the `EventWS` a managed CDI bean (for example, `@RequestScoped`).  You may want to show the remaining config (`web.xml` and the JAX-RS annotations that you ommitted) for further help.

Update to answer the question in the comment:

Your are using a non-standard servlet definition.  I don't know whether the jersey servlet respects the CDI annotations, therefore you might want to try this in `web.xml` instead:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>javax.ws.rs.core.Application</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/resources/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

(or subclass `javax.ws.rs.core.Application` with the `@ApplicationPath` annotation.  See the [Java EE 7 Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/jaxrs002.htm) for details.)

And then don't for get to annotate your `EventWS` with `@RequestScoped` or `@SessionScoped` or whatever fits your needs.

Comment: Why does @Stateless annotation is ignored in WAR?

Comment: I updated my post to include JAX-RS annotations and web.xml. How can I make EventsWS a CDI bean? What annotations and xml config files do I need (beans.xml?)?

Comment: @Sriram because in an EAR application, the EJB beans are to be deployed in an EJB module.

Comment: I am still struggling with this problem. I created a subclass of ``Applcation`` with ``@ApplicationPath("rest/")``, commented all my web.xml, removed ``@Stateless`` from EventsWS and added ``@RequestScoped`` and I still get the error.

Comment: can you post a minimal (non-)working code example? Did you include a `beans.xml`?

Comment: Yes, I included a beans.xml inside my WEB-INF folder with no explicit bean declaration, just the open/close tags and namespaces. Here is some sample code not working: http://pastebin.com/vL8jhCQJ Let me know if you need more info.

Comment: pasting some random code to pastebin does not really help when the directory structure is important.  This should really work, even without the `@RequestScoped` annotation, see this small sample project, which works flawlessly on JBoss 7.1.1: https://github.com/lngr/WebServiceTest

Comment: @Alexander Langer - untrue.  you can still use "simplified packaging" inside an EAR file.  the only thing the EAR file changes is the enclosing classloader, deployment context, and jndi semantics.