# EJB JAX-RS nullPointerException

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb, jax-rs

I want to Inject a `EJB` in a `jax-rs` class. I get always a `NullPointerException`.
Can anybody help me. 
The Jax-RS class has following construct:

```
@Stateless
@Path("uom")
public class RestUOM {

    @EJB UOMService memoryService;

    @GET
    @Path("memory/{hostId}")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_XML)
    public String checkMemory(@PathParam("hostId") Integer hostId){
        Memory memory = this.memoryService.getMemory(hostId); //this.memoryService is null
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        JAXB.marshal(memory, sw);
        String result = sw.toString();
        return result;
    }
```

Why is the local variable `memoryService` always null?

Comment: What kind of interface does your bean have (local, remove, none) and where is the ejb located. Also what version of Java EE are you using?

Comment: The bean is a localbean. the UOMService class is in another package as the RestUOM class. 
Java EE Version: 1.7

Comment: Make sure that you're not deploying Jersey or RestEASY jars (or any other JAX-RS implementation) with your application

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I deployed a unused jersey jar. 

I wanted to upvote your awnser but i clicked it twice, sry.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Inject an EJB into JAX-RS (RESTful service)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3027834/inject-an-ejb-into-jax-rs-restful-service)