# Jersey and EJB stateless example, EJB instance is null

Tags: jersey, ejb, grizzly

I am making a simple RESTful service using JAVAX RS and EJB in order to create a singleton object as a global variable.

I initiated the service as follows:

```java
    import org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServer;
    import org.glassfish.jersey.grizzly2.httpserver.GrizzlyHttpServerFactory;
    import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;

    final ResourceConfig rc = new ResourceConfig().packages("service_folder");
    GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer(URI.create(BASE_URI), rc);
```

I am currently just testing the @Stateless example.

Firstly, I create a class in a random folder, and the content as follows:

```java
    import javax.ejb.Stateless;
    import java.util.Date;


    @Stateless
    public class Service {
        public Date getCurrentDate(){
            return new Date();
        }
    }
```

Then I create the resource file in the **service_folder** mentioned in the very beginning:

```java
    @Stateless
    @Path("current")
    public class ServiceFacade {

        @EJB
        Service service;

        @GET
        public String getDate(){
            return service.getCurrentDate().toString();
        }

    }
```

The current situation is that whenever I access *BASE_URI/current*, grizzly simply throw an error, and the reason is because **service** in getDate() is null.

My guess is that during the grizzly init., the Service class bean isn't really registered yet.

Please let me know where did I do wrong, thanks!

Comment: Duplicate question [Inject an EJB into JAX-RS (RESTful service)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3027834/inject-an-ejb-into-jax-rs-restful-service) and/or [Dependency injection with Jersey 2.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16216759/dependency-injection-with-jersey-2-0)

Comment: @zyexal But OP followed option #2 in that answer and it's still not working?

Comment: Nope... However I was able to use @Injection to make the singleton instance work. I don't have to use EJB at all. Thanks for the help tho.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Inject an EJB into JAX-RS (RESTful service)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3027834/inject-an-ejb-into-jax-rs-restful-service)